# How do I make cells in a table view use array for their data after the content of array has changed?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm writing a short app in swift which has two screen. On screen one the user enters data and saves it then on screen two the data is displayed in a `tableView`. However I cant seem to get the `tableView` to adapt to the changed `array`.

I've looked around and cant seem to find a solution, however I'm new to this so I might be looking in the wrong places.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! BunchOfCells
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    if tasks.count != 0 {cell.label.text = tasks[indexPath.item]["Title"]}
    return cell
}

func createTask(){
    let decider = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "buttonPressed") as? Bool
    if (decider == true){
        let nameOfTask = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "taskName") as! String
        let importanceOfTask = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "importance") as! String
        let dateOfTask = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "taskDate") as! String
        let desOfTask = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "taskDescription") as! String
        taskInfo["Title"] = nameOfTask
        taskInfo["Importance"] = importanceOfTask
        taskInfo["Date"] = dateOfTask
        taskInfo["Description"] = desOfTask
        tasks.append(taskInfo)
        print(tasks)          
    }


var tasks: [[String:String]] = [] as Array

var taskInfo: [String:String] = ["Title":"", "Importance":"", "Date":"", "Description":""]



let tableview: UITableView = {

    let tv = UITableView()

    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    tv.separatorColor = UIColor.white

    return tv

}()



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let NumOfCell = tasks.count

    return NumOfCell

}
```

`tasks` is the `array` storing a multiple `dictionaries` with similar content.

My problem is that when another `dictionary` is added to the `array` the `cells` in the table view don't change. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Unrelated but there is `string(forKey:` and `bool(forKey:` in `UserDefaults`. And there is no reason to set the background color of the table view 100 times in `cellForRow` and the check `tasks.count != 0` is redundant, too. If `tasks` is empty `cellForRow` is not even called.

Comment: The "tasks.count" is needed otherwise when the array is empty an error comes up saying "index out of range"

Comment: Then you made another mistake. In the standard implementation of the data source methods `cellForRow` isn't called if `numberOfRows` returns 0.

Comment: I know this might be a stupid question since you don't have much info, but could you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Edit your question and add the declaration of `tasks` and the `numberOfRowsInSection` method

Comment: Don't create the table view instance in code. It's **not** the instance in the storyboard. Declare an `IBOutlet` and connect the table view in Interface Builder to the outlet. Connect also `datasource` of the table view to the controller and add conformance to `UITableViewDataSource`. Then PGDev's suggestion will work and the code won't throw an out-of-range exception.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call **`reloadData()`** on `tableView` after you created a new task, i.e.

```
func createTask(){
    let decider = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonPressed")
    if decider {
        //your rest of the code...
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Don't forget to create an `outlet` for `tableView` in your `viewController`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

And ofcourse, as @vadian suggested, `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` implementation must be like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! BunchOfCells
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    cell.label.text = tasks[indexPath.item]["Title"]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Actually there must be an outlet. Note the spelling in `cellForRow` .

Comment: @vadian Didn't get you. Did I make any error in the code?

Comment: No, you didn’t but obviously there is an outlet `tableview` (with lowercase v) in the class.

Comment: @vadian oh ok. Got that. Thanks for the catch. I updated that in the answer. Actually I used the tableView parameter in the method itself.

Comment: It’s highly recommended to use **always** the given `tableView` parameter in the data source and delegate methods.

Comment: @vadian Right. I'm doing the exact same thing. Thanks for the information 

Comment: Will creating an outlet by doing 'let tableview: UITableView = {}' work the same?

Comment: Also, without the "if tasks.count != 0" when the app is run with an empty array it crashes due to index out of range.

Comment: Outlets connect your interface to the controller. So writing let tableView = UITableView() is not the same. And return tasks.count in numberOfRows method to get rid of that crash.